# Unable to access packaged custom labels from outside the managed package

Tags: customlabel

I am able access the custom labels created in my org, using Apex, but not the custom labels from a managed package installed in my org. The documentation does not have a specific example to access namespaced custom labels in Apex. I am developing lightning components in a developer edition org (not scratch org).

I have tried the following ways:

System.Label.namespace.CustomLabelName
System.Label.namespace__CustomLabelName
Label.namespace.CustomLabelName
Label.namespace__CustomLabelName

and got the following error message:

External string does not exist: CustomLabelName

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/labels_apex.htm

Has anybody been able to access packaged custom labels from outside the package?

Comment: `Label.namespace.labelname` or `System.namespace.labelname` is the correct syntax. Whatever is going on is something else.

Comment: +1 to comment posted by sfdcfox. Check if the label is "protected"

Comment: @SalesforceArchitect Looks like that was the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments...

The correct syntax is System.Label.*Namespace*.*CustomLabelName*.

This also requires the managed [CustomLabel to have `protected`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customlabels.htm) set to `false` so the subscriber org can access it.