# External String does not exist error when doing a validation deployment

Tags: deployment, class, customlabel

As part of a new development, I am deploying a set of metadata. I have an ApexClass and a CustomLabel among other things. The ApexClass is making use of a new CustomLabel I am also deploying, however, I when it is validating, the ApexClass fails with the following error:

> External string does not exist: Invalid_Relationship_Error.

The relevant code is this one:

```
throw new InvalidRelationshipException(Label.Invalid_Relationship_Error);
```

And the label looks like:

```
<labels>
    <fullName>Invalid_Relationship_Error</fullName>
    <categories>Whatever</categories>
    <language>en_US</language>
    <protected>true</protected>
    <shortDescription>Invalid Relationship Error</shortDescription>
    <value>Whatever</value>
</labels>
```

Has anyone faced this before and has a solution and explanation for this?

Comment: Can you show the deployment package.xml which you are building?

Comment: I believe your issue might be this. Your label is protected, check @sfdcfox comment : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/247456/unable-to-access-packaged-custom-labels-from-outside-the-managed-package

Comment: @Nagendra Singh you are right, the label is protected, but we are an ISV and it is part of out own package and usually we do not need to use namespace syntax, in fact, we have several references to other custom labels in the whole code without using namespaces and they work just fine.